# How to get the index path of a tableviewcell that's populated from an array?

Tags: ios, arrays, multidimensional-array, nsindexpath, uitableview

I have a tableviewcell with 5 different cells. Each view has a label with one of the following inside of it. 1 textfields, 1 text, view 1, switch, or 1 slider. I am trying to find the tableviewcell for row at index path so I can retrieve the information that the user has entered. Below is the code I have for the cells and different switches. I just need to know how to achieve this if possible. Thanks (p.s) I was thinking about just tagging the elements instead of finding cell for row so that's why you will see tag code.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)listCell:(UITableView *)tableView IndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
static NSString *textFieldIdentifier = @"textFieldCell";
static NSString *textViewIdentifier = @"textViewCell";
static NSString *switchIdentifier = @"switchCell";
static NSString *seekBarIdentifier = @"seekBarCell";
static NSString *datePickerIdentifier = @"datePickerCell";

//DBSectionDetailsTableViewCell *cell = (DBSectionDetailsTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:textViewIdentifier];
UITableViewCell *cell6 =  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:datePickerIdentifier];


results = [listArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];


if([indexPath row] < listArray.count)
{
    if (([[results objectAtIndex:2]isEqualToString:@"EditText"]))
    {

        DBSectionDetailsTableViewCell *cell2 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:textFieldIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell2.titleLabel.text = [results objectAtIndex:1];
        //title button
        cell2.textField.tag = [indexPath row];
        cell2.textField.delegate = self;

        [cell2.textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidEndEditing:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    return cell2;
    }

    else if (([[results objectAtIndex:2]isEqualToString:@"EditTextLarge"]))
    {
        TextViewTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:textViewIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

      //  cell = textFieldCell;
        cell.titleLabel.text = [results objectAtIndex:1];
        cell.textView.tag = [indexPath row];
        cell.textView.delegate = self;
       // [cell.textView addTarget:self action:@selector(textViewDidEndEditing:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


        return cell;
    }

    else if (([[results objectAtIndex:2]isEqualToString:@"Switch"]))
    {

        SwitchTableViewCell *cell3 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:switchIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


       // cell3 = switchCell;
        cell3.titleLabel.text = [results objectAtIndex:1];
        cell3.switchOutlet.tag = [indexPath row];


        return cell3;
    }

    else if (([[results objectAtIndex:2]isEqualToString:@"SeekBar"]))
    {

        SeekBarTableViewCell *cell4 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:seekBarIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


        //cell4 = seekBarCell;
        cell4.titleLabel.text = [results objectAtIndex:1];
        cell4.slider.tag = [indexPath row];

       return cell4;
    }

    else if (([[results objectAtIndex:2]isEqualToString:@"DatePicker"]))
    {

        DatePickerTableViewCell *cell5 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:datePickerIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        //cell5 = datePickerCell;
        cell5.titleLabel.text = [results objectAtIndex:1];
        cell5.datePicker.tag = [indexPath row];
        cell5.datePicker.delegate = self;

        [cell5.datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerDidEndEditing:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        return cell5;
    }


}

//UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


return cell6;
```

}

Comment: Also, the tableview is dynamic of course because the tableviewcells are being populated by whatever the consumer sets on the backend.

Comment: Very confusing.  If you have the cell and want to know the index path, use `indexPathForCell`.  But it sounds you have an array index and want to associate that with an index path -- that's the responsibility of your dataSource object.

Comment: Yes, understood... I was trying to use something like this
    NSIndexPath *newIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

    DBSectionDetailsTableViewCell *cell2 = (DBSectionDetailsTableViewCell *)[listTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:newIndex];

in my "save" function but I was still returning "null/nil" on everything. I think going the route of tagging the buttons may be better, I just wanted to see if I can use NSIndex to achieve what I want to without doing all of the tags and additional function calls etc.

Comment: UITableView `cellForRow..` returns "An object representing a cell of the table **or nil if the cell is not visible** or indexPath is out of range."  Cells that are not currently being displayed do not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch visible cells from a table using `[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]`. Cells that are offscreen will be removed from the `UITableView` and you will not be able to access them at all as they will have been put back into the reusable cell queue.

---

**Note 1**: You shouldn't be relying on your `UITableView` to store your current data state. It throws away cells that are scrolled off-screen, so if you don't persist your data in another place, it will be lost forever.

---

**Note 2**: This code isn't particularly safe:

```
results = [listArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
if([indexPath row] < listArray.count) // This is always true.
                                      // If it isn't true, the above
                                      // objectAtIndex: will crash your app.
```

Comment: Thanks, and it will always be true because there will always be data on the backend... "the list array" unless it get hacked and all data deleted if that happens then well... the whole app won't work in general because it's based on the database.

But thanks a lot

Comment: If it's always true, why bother checking it at all?

Comment: I suppose I can take it out now but in the beginning the backend for this portion of the app wasn't finished yet. So instead of deleting it I just switched it. I clean up my code up my code at the end of completing a process, but this process isn't quite complete so I still have commented lines etc. to strip out. But once again thanks for the extra eye. I think i'll just tag the items i'm trying to retrieve the information for. I was just trying to avoid the extra functions that goes with that.

Answer (score 0):

You should save the information as the user enters it for each cell because you can't reach a cell once it gets out of the view to be reused later.